# Getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException" if I am making thread sleep for 30 minutes

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, java-8

I want to make an API call but wait for 30 minutes post that I create a JWT token and call the API,
But I am getting below error , the exception starts after the thread resumes to process, Below is some line of code

```
log.debug("Reached here ======================== {}"+ Instant.now());
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(30);
log.error("again starting" +Instant.now());
String accesstoken = "Bearer " + jwtTokenUtils.getToken();
```

jwttokenclass:-

```
    public class JwtTokenUtils {

@Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key:secret-key}")
private String secretKey;

@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
}

public String getToken() {
    String authToken = getAuthorizationHeader();
    
    if (authToken != null && authToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        return authToken.substring(7);
    } 
}

public String getAuthorizationHeader() {
    log.debug("Inside getAuthorizationHeader()");
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    if(request != null) {
        return request.getHeader("Authorization");
    } 
}
```

Getting below error:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you
referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or
processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you
are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In
this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose 
the current request.
at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.1.19.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.19.RELEASE]
at com.dummy.org.util.JwtTokenUtils.getAuthorizationHeader(JwtTokenUtils.java:45) ~[classes!/:2021.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at com.dummy.org.util.JwtTokenUtils.getToken(JwtTokenUtils.java:34) ~[classes!/:2021.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

I have written below code snippet, but getting error

```
log.debug("Reached here ======================== {}"+ Instant.now());
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(30);
log.error("again starting" +Instant.now());
String accesstoken = "Bearer " + jwtTokenUtils.getToken();
```

Expected:- new token should be created and API call should be successfull

Comment: Why do you think that the error has any connection to the `sleep` call? What is `jwtTokenUtils`? How was that variable assigned or initialized? I don't know Spring, but the exception obviously was raised _by_ Spring (`at org.springframework...`), and `IllegalStateException` probably means that you are using Spring in some incorrect way.

Comment: @SolomonSlow updated jwt token class , I am just Autowiring it

Comment: `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` is only going to work if you call it while processing a request. Are you doing that? What happens if you call `getToken()` before waiting 30 minutes?

Comment: You're trying to access the headers of a 30 minute old web request?  Are you trying to block one of your app server's handler threads for 30 minutes?  You should probably get the headers first and save them in the thread that's waiting.  (and then switch to a proper delayed queueing mechanism :) )

Comment: @erickson issue with getToken() only, its giving that particular error without even sleep

Comment: Okay, you should rewrite your question to include only the parts that make a difference. You are sending people in the wrong direction by including unnecessary details, and leaving out the important parts. This method is only going to work while servicing a call to a web service endpoint, from the thread that is handling the call. Is that the case here?